# Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets

Tags: react-native, expo

Can't merge pod_target_xcconfig for pod targets: ["expo-dev-menu", "Main", "SafeAreaView", "Vendored"]. Singular build setting DEFINES_MODULE has different values

I have upgraded expo version from 47 to 49 . Then I need to install pods for Xcode but I have this error. The node.js version is 16. I have removed node_modules and package-lock.json also but I don't know what should I do exactly to solve this problem .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i have similar issue, were you able to solve it?